# Is it possible to make custom WordN integers?

Tags: haskell

In the `Data.Word` module, it provides types like Word8, Word16, etc.

Is there a way to implement my own Word type, such as Word4 (efficiently)?

Comment: [Here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Word.html#line-157) you have the implementation of  `Word8` type. Just make a new type `Word4` with modified instances for 4 bits.

Comment: I do not really get why you want to implement a `Word4`. A computer has a "word size": the number of bits that are stored in the same "row" in memory. Anything smaller can only be fetched by fetching the full row, and then masking some bits. Usually it is not a good idea to work with smaller items, since it only introduces more overhead: masking away the noise surrounding it. You can implement a `Word4` to make the masking transparent (and to boost efficiency of some operations). But `Word4` thus will probably be less efficient than `Word8`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, Mainly because the program I'm making works with 4 bit units at some points so I would like a data type for it.

Answer (score 1):

[SBV](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/sbv) package has an example for it: [Data.SBV.Examples.Misc.Word4](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/sbv-7.3/docs/src/Data.SBV.Examples.Misc.Word4.html).